# Program in C works on Ubuntu won't work in other OS

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu

My code won't work in any other OS other than Ubuntu, well maybe not whole program, but some parts of it. Let's start from the beginning. First, I wrote code which worked OK, but I needed SU and I had to change it.

I changed some flags and on Ubuntu everything works fine but in other OS Code of part which won't work. So I wrote parts of code which are related, from what I saw program won't enter if.

```
    //attack From P1:
if(!fork()) {
    struct Battle battle;
    while(1) {
        **if(msgrcv(IPC_ID, &battle, IPC_size, Attack_From_P1, 0)** == IPC_size) 
{
            char strLoses[IPC_size] = "";
            int kogo = battle.kogo;
            char lose[IPC_size];
            int lin = battle.jednostki[0];//units
            int hin = battle.jednostki[1];
            int hor = battle.jednostki[2];
            opusc(semid, 0);//down
            int intShmLin1 = atoi(shmLin1);
            int intShmHin1 = atoi(shmHin1);
            int intShmHor1 = atoi(shmHor1);
            int intLin;
            int intHin;
            int intHor;

}
void wyslij_Komunikat(int signal, char text[IPC_size], int number) {//send Message
msg.mtype = signal;
strcpy(msg.mtext, text);
msg.number = number;
int id = msgsnd(IPC_ID, &msg, IPC_size, 0);
if(id == -1) {
    perror("Problem podczas wysyłania wiadomosci");//Problem while sending message
    exit(1);
}
```

And specifically nothing happens, another problem I have is in home I have only Ubuntu on which this works without any problem.

```
            else if(strcmp(consoleInput, "atak") == 0) { atak(playerID);//attack
```

First block of code is used to sendMessage(), second check what command the user used.

### Edit

The problem is, on Ubuntu I don't get any error/warning, everything works, on other OS, I don't get any error/warning, Forfeit and Attack won't work.

Comment: Can you reduce this to show _just_ the part(s) of the code that are not working?  When you say "doesn't work" what specifically happens?  Have you tried sending debug outout to Standard Error to make sure your code is doing what you think it is?

Comment: many of us here are unfamiliar with the (I'm guessing) Polish printouts of `perror()` can you tel us  also the integer value of  `errno` and what constant from `<errno.h>` that matches

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "other OS"? `msgsnd` and `msgrcv` are not cross-platform.

Comment: Well maybe i used wrong word (i'm sorry 40h without sleep), but it works on Ubuntu, on Debian or Linux it won't. And i have no idea why does it matter what i use. (ubuntu/debian etc)

Comment: msgsend and msgrcv are on anything with a BSD network stack, which is  almost all desktop operating systems.